# What is the best way to implement a windows service which performs actions on schedule?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a database table (a schedule) which maps `datetime` to some action. What is the best way to implement a windows service which can perform those actions on specified time? The only thing that comes to mind is to query table from the service with some interval, but I think that there is more proper way. Do you have any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve with your schedule?

Comment: Have you considered Scheduled Tasks? All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Scheduled Tasks

Comment: @unlimit The schedule is being filled by another application. And there is a requirement not to use integrated scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [Quartz .NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)? It could be a possible solution :

> Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that
>   can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.

Here's the [feature page](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/features.html) and a [tutorial](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/).